# How to use the data from get request in a post request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, spoonacular

I’m kind of new to APIs and currently working on a project using the Spoonacular API. Im trying to build a meal planner website. At the moment, I’m working on the “Add To Meal Plan” feature which is a post method. To get the information for the post method, I think have to use a get method to retrieve recipe information from the API using a Recipe ID. I’m using TempData to store the information I get back from the get method so I can use it in my post method. Is this the most efficient way to be doing this? Or is it better to have my get and post requests be in the same method so I don’t have to store anything?

Currently, I’m using TempData to store the recipe information. It works but just not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this. I’m storing an object that I’ve serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TempData is an acceptable approach for storing temporary data that needs to be passed from one request to another. It's part of the ASP.NET Core framework and provides a simple way to store values between multiple requests.

However, depending on your specific use case, there might be other ways to store this information that are more efficient. For example, if you want to store the recipe information for multiple users and persist it between sessions, you could consider using a database or a caching solution.

If the information you're storing is specific to a single user session, then TempData might be the best choice as it's relatively lightweight and easy to use.

In terms of combining the get and post requests into a single method, it's not necessary to do so. However, it might be more efficient in terms of network requests and server load if you can reduce the number of requests that need to be made to retrieve the required information.

Tell me if this helps :)